# Member Function and a non-object

Tags: php, xml

I have created a simple function for fetching xml:

```
function meteor(){
    $request_url = "http://site.com/xml.xml";
    $xml = simplexml_load_file($request_url) or die("feed not loading");
    return $xml;
 }
```

But I cant call to this function:

```
$xmls = new meteor();
echo $xmls->Kemo->Area;
```

I have not any output because meteor in not a class. In this situation, how can fetch data from function? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: show us some errors ? and try var_dump the xmls variable.

Comment: Try `$xmls = meteor();` (without the `new` keyword).

Comment: @Robert; "Trying to get property of non-object", $xmls = meteor(); works perfect.
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$xmls = meteor();
$xmls->Kemo->Area;
```

Comment: you have earned the speed demon badge (well, it there was one).

Comment: hehe thanks :) I'll keep that badge on my imaginary almost-badge-collection-table ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `new` only with classes, to create a new object from that class. `meteor` is a function, not a class. What you want is to call the function instead, simply like this:

```
$xmls = meteor();
```

Answer (score 1):

meteor is a function not a class. i don't think you can create a

```
new meteor();
```

Answer (score 1):

The basic code is wrong. **Always remember that you cannot use the "new" keyword for instantiating functions. This "new" keyword will only work for instantiating classes into objects.**

Try calling the function directly into your code, for fetching the appropriate value. But before that I think you will need to modify your "meteor()" function according to what you want to achieve.

Hope it helps.